# How Can I Retrieve the Output from Mutliple CheckBoxList Selections & Place in Email Text File in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

In my ASP.Net/C# site, I have a page which acts as a form and records the user's information. The form then sends this information to an email, by way of a formatted text file in my `App Data` folder. All of the input appears in the email, however, when I test to select multiple checkbox items, only one selection appears -- here's the formatted text file code:

```
Customer Name:     ##CustName##
Phone Number:      ##PhoneNumber##
Service Address:   ##Address##
City/State:        ##lstCitySelect##
ZipCode:           ##ZipCode##

Service Type:      ##ServiceType##
Service Date:      ##ServiceDate##
Service Time:      ##ServiceTime##
```

And here's the code-behind of the form I'm using to process all this into the email:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ScheduleForm.txt");
        string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##CustName##", txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text);            
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##PhoneNumber##", txtPhone.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Address##", txtAddress.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##lstCitySelect##", lstCitySelect.SelectedValue);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ZipCode##", txtZipCode.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ServiceType##", chkServiceOption.SelectedValue);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ServiceDate##", txtDatePopulate.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ServiceTime##", txtTimePopulate.Text);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Details##", txtDetails.Text);

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.Subject = "Response from web site";
        myMessage.Body = mailBody;

        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("email@myemail.com", "From Sender");
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@myemail.com", "To Recipient"));

        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);

        Message.Visible = true;
        FormTable.Visible = false;
    }            
}
```

My issue is with the `chkServiceOption` CheckBoxList control not returning all selected instances of "checked boxes" in the email. I couldn't find a class to pull out the index of selected values. Can some please suggest what I can use or do to accomplish this? I've included screen shots of the form before submitting, and after it hits the email -- notice only **one instance of a service** is pulled.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx):

> To determine the selected items in the CheckBoxList control, iterate through the Items collection and test the Selected property of each item in the collection.

So you have to do something like this:

```
var services = chkServiceOption.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                     .Where(c => c.Selected)
                                     .Select(c => c.Text);

var servicesStr = string.Join(", ", services);
```

This is just a LINQ-ification of the following loop:

```
string ret = "";

foreach(var item in checkbox.items)
{
    if(item.Selected)
    {
        if (ret.Length > 0)
        {
            ret += ", ";
        }

        ret += item.Text;
    }
}
```

The idea is that you have to loop through each of the items in the `CheckBoxList`, check whether they are selected, then add them to a collection. I chose a comma-separated string for my "collection" in this example since I figured that's what you'd want in your email, but you can see how it could be any other type of collection as well.

**Edit:**

This is just addressing a request in comments to explain the LINQ query.

There are four basic steps I took here. I'll just go over each.

1. `chkServiceOption.Items`: This is the same for the `foreach` as LINQ. I assume you understand where that's coming from.
2. `.Cast<ListItem>()`: Here's where we start doing interesting things. The [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) class only implements `IEnumerable`, not the `IEnumerable<T>` that's required for LINQ queries to run. Thus, we have to cast each element to be of type `ListItem`. Behind the scenes, this is basically just a `foreach` loop that iterates over the `ListItemCollection` and casts each element.
3. `.Where(c => c.Selected)`: Here's where we start using LINQ. We're now dealing with an `IEnumerable<ListItem>`, so we can run queries based on that knowledge. The code behind here loops through each element, then only returns the elements that pass the predicate. In our case, that means it only returns the ones where `c.Selected`, which is just a well-known syntactic shortcut for `c.Selected == true`.
4. `.Select(c => c.Text)`: Now we have only the elements that we want, but they're still all typed as `ListItem` which isn't particularly useful to users. We want the text of each `ListItem` (checkbox), so we loop through each item and select the value of the `Text` property.
5. `string.Join`: This isn't really LINQ-y either, but basically now we just want to put in a comma between each element so that it better-resembles a human-readable list.

Comment: Aren't you missing a ToArray() call?

Comment: Nope, I thought about that though. But `string.Join` has an overload that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`, so it's all good.

Comment: So it does, thanks I didn't know about that overload.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Connect the dots please. Thanks.

Comment: @DesignerMind Sure. What dots would you like connected? I added in a non-LINQ version and explained a bit, does that clarify at all? Let me know if I can help more.

Comment: I am first year ASP.Net programmer, and not strong on this loops. You'll have to let me know whether write this in separate code block like `protected void chkServiceOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`, or within my btnSubmit stub and how I may begin to approach to implement. Please note that in the end, `mailBody = mailBody.Replace(##ServiceType##,chkServiceOption.SomethingHere` must reference the added items.

Comment: You can put it wherever you'd like, it's giving you a string. You could just put it at the top of your `btnSubmit_Click` event, then change the line to `mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ServiceType##", servicesStr);`. That would work.

Comment: Very good. I shall try this implementation after dinner, and let you know the results. Thank you!

Comment: This works wonderfully, and I've learned something major in the process. Thank you so much. I gave you the credit, but can you explain the LINQ version to me, just so I'm familiar with it? What's the difference between the first solution and the LINQ solution?

Comment: Yeah, sure. The difference is mostly just in syntax. The actual code behind is pretty similar for either solution. But I'll add in an explanation of each part of the LINQ query just for good measure. One moment.

Comment: @DesignerMind does that clarify it? I wasn't really sure at which level you were hoping to get the clarification, but that's a good summary of what's going on at each step.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that chkServiceType option can have multiple (or no) selected values, not just the one.  Your code is looking for a single value when you need to iterate of the control's item collection to see if a child item is selected.  I am a bit rusty on it but it should look something like:

```
   foreach(var item in checkbox.items)
   {
      if(item.Selected)
      {
          //Do Something
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chkServiceOption.Items[0].Selected

chkServiceOption.Items[1].Selected

chkServiceOption.Items[2].Selected

chkServiceOption.Items[0].Text
```

Examine those in the debugger or just append to email so you can see the values......

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of `chkServiceOption.SelectedValue` suggest to me that it refers, in fact, to a singular value, which would explain the behaviour you're seeing.  You'll probably need to loop through the items in the CheckBoxList and test whether each is checked.  Try something like this:

```
string serviceOptionTxt = "";
for (int i = 0; i < chkServiceOption.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (chkServiceOption.Items[i].Selected)
        serviceOptionTxt += chkServiceOption.Items[i].Value + " ";
        // Or possibly?
        //serviceOptionTxt += chkServiceOption.Items[i].Text + " ";
    }
}
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ServiceType##", serviceOptionTxt);
```

Comment: Your portion which contains the `mailBody = mailBody` snippet cannot be implemented. You cannot have `, serviceOptionTxt` there... it must reference `chkSeviceOption` and tie something to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... The code does reference chkServiceOption, it iterates through each of its items.  If you're referring to the String.Replace, it works with any strings.  Either way Matthew Haugen's solution is more elegant, and has both a LINQ and non-LINQ version, but there's nothing about my code which "cannot be implemented".